# Different heads on Dodge Magnum 360

Tags: engine, dodge, ram

I'm working on a 98 Dodge Ram 2500 with a Magnum 360 V8 (roller cam shaft). It had a cracked head on one side, so I purchased a pair of remanned heads from an eBay retailer. These heads are the 466/671 combination (as expected). The problem is, the heads which I pulled off are an identical set (both 466 heads - this engine has had head work done before, obviously). I need to know which one goes on which side (driver's/passenger). I read on a couple of different sites which say they are identical, which I am doubting. The reason I am doubting is due to the fact everywhere I've looked, it specifies for different heads. (If they are exactly the same, or interchangeable, why would they make and specify two different heads??). I've seen one site (actually a seller) which actually specifies which head is supposed to go on which side, but it uses right/left. I have a major problem with this, as some people view right/left while standing in front of the car, while others use the view as sitting in the vehicle. Driver side and passenger side are much more descriptive. Also, if anyone knows what exactly the differences are, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After an exhaustive search on the internet, I came to the conclusion that while the two heads have a different part number and are different in some very minor ways, I have just thrown the heads on there and done the deed. If there is a significant difference I couldn't see, there doesn't seem to be an issue with them. The truck started right up without any leaks or problems with the heads that I can tell. It is my understanding (now) that it doesn't matter which head goes on which side.

Comment: Did you have a chance to check the deck for flatness? If you crack another head, be sure and do this before putting on more heads.

Comment: @kmarsh - I was working on a truck for someone else. The problem turned out to be there was a clogged cat. The owner just continued to push the truck with it that way. These heads are known to have a weak spot between the valves  in the combustion chamber (I believe on the last chamber - either cyl 1 or 7 depending on which bank it's on). That's where it cracked, but it was mainly due to poor ownership. Put the heads/cat on and it ran just fine, no worries. No problems with the deck, but point well taken.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. Yes, the 3.9L Magnum V6 has the same head crack issue, between the valves.

Comment: @kmarsh - Same heads, just two less combustion chambers. The V10 Magnum, same-same, just two more.

Answer (score -1):

The heads are the same, left or right
When it is stated left on the vehicle it means that when you are sitting in the driver's seat, not when looking at the vehicle from the front.